# The code to set 30 second timer

Tags: javascript, html, timer

Please, I am trying  to link all my pages with progressive 30 seconds count timer using JavaScript and html without being recount on page navigation. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, nice to hear that but what is the problem ? ...

Comment: The problem is, when I set the counter to let say 30 minutes, and I spent 10 minutes from one page, if Navigate to next page the counter start new count. And what I want is; the counter to continue from the previous page count.

Comment: Yes but what is the real problem ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

With more information in mind from comments, here's your code:

Somewhere in index.html

```
<div id="counter"></div>
```

YourScript.js

```
// Simplifies getting the value of a cookie
function getCookie(name)
  {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
  }

// Max time for cookie
var count = 30;
if(document.cookie && document.cookie.match('counter')) {
    // Set value of counter to match the cookie
    count = getCookie('counter');
}

// Runs once per second
setInterval(function() {
  // Decrease the value of count by 1 every second  
  count--;
  // if count is less or equal to 0 we move to menu.html
  if(count <= 0) {
    window.location.href="menu.html"
  }
  // Set the text inside the <div id="counter"></div> to the value of counter
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
  // Set the value of the cookie to match the value of our counter variable
  document.cookie = 'counter=' + count;
}, 1000);
```

I created a jsfiddle for this but for some reason jsfiddle doesn't want to create a unique URL for me right now... Go to jsfiddle.net and copy paste this into the script field, and the div into the html area, then press Run several times and you'll see that the counter keeps counting down, persisting between page refreshes.

Comment: Yes I have tried, my problem is to set the single timer to like 10 pages and the timer keep timing when navigating to next page. Nevertheless thank you for your consideration

Comment: That code should've been in your question directly because your question did not at all make it clear this is what you wanted... I'll fix it for you within an hour or two, doing other stuff right now.

Comment: @IbrahimShehuSafana Don't post code in comments. Never. It is not formatted and hard to read. Please edit your question and post your code in it.

Comment: Ok, I sorry mistake, this is because I am s beginner in coding. very grateful for your help

Comment: @Symon hyll thanks so much for the above code let me try it.

Comment: @Symon hyll the code really helpful, but what if I want the timer to count across the let say index1 index2 index3 with the single timer count, what shall I do?

Comment: Assuming they are all on the same domain the cookie is universal on your site so this solution works fine.

Comment: If they arent on the same domain make a single domain for them all and use iframe to display the other sites and have the cookie stuff happen on the preview site. You cant sync a countdown across sites without e.g. a REST api or annoying PHP solutions.